# Вывести данные из двух таблиц в ответ, связь OneToOne

Tags: java, spring

есть небольшая структура проекта: таблица Product связанная отношением OneToOne с таблицей City. Сценарий следующий: один товар (Product) производится в конкретном городе, регионе. Вопрос как реализовать связь OneToOne между таблицей Product и City, чтобы метод вернул в итоге структуру указанную ниже? (поле "city")

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productName": "Супрастин",
        "productCode": 350,
        "bareCode": 1432356784,
        "produce": "Тест2",
        "type": "Лекарства",
        "price": 31,
        "city": {
                  "id": 10,
                  "name": "Владивосток"
                }
    }...
 ]
```

Реализация:

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_entity")
@Data
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private Integer productCode;

    @Column(name = "bare_code")
    private Integer bareCode;

    @Column(name = "produce")
    private String produce;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;

    

    @OneToOne
    private City city;

    
}
```

City

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        productService.addProduct(product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(product);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getOne(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Product product) {
        productService.update(id, product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.delete(id));
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    // Создание продукта

    public Product addProduct(Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    // Получение продуктов


    public Iterable<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    // Получение продукта

    public Product getOne(Long id) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(id).get();
        return product;
    }

    // Обновление продукта

    public Product update(Long id, Product product) {
        product.setId(id);
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    // Удаление продукта

    public Long delete(Long id) {
        productRepository.deleteById(id);
        return id;
    }

    // Поисковые запросы

    public List<Product> getProductByProductName(String productName) {
        return productRepository.findProductByProductNameContaining(productName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) - если ты хочешь, чтобы при добавлении сохранение в бд шло совместно с другой таблицей, также и удаление будет происходить по такому же принципу

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) - сработает только на добавление, если ты удалишь продукт, то не будет удален город

Comment: Не удается вывести поле city в запросе:

нужно выводить следующую структуру: скриншот структура: https://ibb.co/wRWHXcV, для этого полагаю нужно корректно связать таблицы Product с City но пока не понимаю как.

Comment: у вас при запросе не возвращает city или запрос не проходит?

Comment: @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
 private City city;

Добавь связь с помощью @JoinColumn

Comment: Нашел ошибку, понял почему не получалось, благодарю. В классе City не были созданы сеттеры и геттеры или поставить аннотацию Data

Comment: Понял, хорошо, что вы разобрались)